# Run ansible playbook from PHP and get notified when it's done

Tags: php, ansible

I want to run a script on a remote server using ansible playbook from my PHP page.
Is there a way to get notified when the remote script ( ansible paybook) has finished.
I thought to use a task to insert a row in my database from the distant server but i don't think it's possibe.

What's the best way to do this :

1. Call ansible playbook from php to run remote script
2. Get the Stdout, Sterr and output of the remote script
3. Get notified when the script has finished so i can show the output on my php page.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [callback plugins](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/plugins/callback.html),

For example, in your `ansible.cfg` you could have something like

```
[defaults]
callback_whitelist = timer, stderr, mail
```

This means it will use the plugin [timer](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/plugins/callback/timer.html), [stderr](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/plugins/callback/stderr.html) and [mail](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/plugins/callback/mail.html).

- timer - Adds time to play stats
- stderr - Splits output, sending failed tasks to stderr
- mail - Sends failure events via email

Check the existing plugin list here: [callback.html#plugin-list](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/plugins/callback.html#plugin-list), or by using:

```
ansible-doc -t callback -l
```

If the existing plugins are not enough you can always create your own: [developing_plugins](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/dev_guide/developing_plugins.html#callback-plugins)

Comment: I'm looking to run some long script on a remote nodes( 3-6min), i don't want a mail callback but something like a databse insertion script when the task is done.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a queuing system. Like: https://github.com/queue-interop/queue-interop

You put the job in a queue, when the playbook is done, you write result in database.